# Logic Puzzle of Diamonds and sons

Tags: puzzle, contest-math

I came across a math problem and I need a solution for this. An old man has 49 diamonds. Each one has a different worth as `$1, $2, $3, ….. $49`. He has 7 sons and he wanted to give them equal number of diamonds of equal worth. How the diamonds will be Divided?

Comment: What did you already try about it ?.

Comment: One child will get 7 diamonds and that is worth of **$175**

Comment: Good! So now have you tried to find sets of 7 numbers adding up to 175?

Comment: Yes. I think there is logical way to do divisions like this. It would be great anyone explain that.

Comment: Would this be considered cheating?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square#Method_for_constructing_a_magic_square_of_odd_order

Comment: @Mike This is the one I needed. Its working fine for all conditions. We can provide two solutions for this question through this. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So let's do this in general. Say we have $n^2$ diamonds with worths $1, 2, \ldots, n^2$, and we want to divvy them up amongst $n$ sons, equal amounts, etc.

Our total worth is $T = \frac{n^2(n^2+1)}{2}$, so each son gets $S = \frac{n(n^2+1)}{2} = \frac{n^3+n}{2}$.

Now let's look at two matrices, $M$ and $N$.

Let $M$ be such that $M_{ij} = (j - i) \pmod n$ and $N$ be such that $N_{ij} = n(j+1)$. In the case that $n = 4$, then we have $M = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 3 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
 2 & 3 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and $N = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 4 & 8 & 12 & 16 \\
 4 & 8 & 12 & 16 \\
 4 & 8 & 12 & 16 \\
 4 & 8 & 12 & 16 \\
\end{array}
\right)$.

Now let's look at the sum of each row. The sum of each row of $N$ is $n+2n+3n+\ldots+n^2 = n\cdot\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = \frac{n^3+n^2}{2}$. The sum of each row of $M$ is $0 + 1 + 2 + \ldots + n - 1 = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} = \frac{n^2-n}{2}$. So let's consider the matrix $N - M$. The sum of each row will then be $\frac{n^3+n^2}{2} - \frac{n^2-n}{2} =\frac{n^3+n}{2} = S$, so if we calculate $N - M$, each row will represent the worth of the diamonds to give to each son.

**Addendum:** I guess I technically didn't answer the question. Letting $n = 7$, we have:

$$N = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 7 & 14 & 21 & 28 & 35 & 42 & 49 \\
 7 & 14 & 21 & 28 & 35 & 42 & 49 \\
 7 & 14 & 21 & 28 & 35 & 42 & 49 \\
 7 & 14 & 21 & 28 & 35 & 42 & 49 \\
 7 & 14 & 21 & 28 & 35 & 42 & 49 \\
 7 & 14 & 21 & 28 & 35 & 42 & 49 \\
 7 & 14 & 21 & 28 & 35 & 42 & 49 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
and
$$M = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

so

$$N - M = \left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 7 & 13 & 19 & 25 & 31 & 37 & 43 \\
 1 & 14 & 20 & 26 & 32 & 38 & 44 \\
 2 & 8 & 21 & 27 & 33 & 39 & 45 \\
 3 & 9 & 15 & 28 & 34 & 40 & 46 \\
 4 & 10 & 16 & 22 & 35 & 41 & 47 \\
 5 & 11 & 17 & 23 & 29 & 42 & 48 \\
 6 & 12 & 18 & 24 & 30 & 36 & 49 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

And note that
$$(N-M)\cdot\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 175 \\
 175 \\
 175 \\
 175 \\
 175 \\
 175 \\
 175 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

as desired.

Comment: Great Work! Approved the answer. Please check your answer for 5 sons and $25. This will help others. Also [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square#Method_for_constructing_a_magic_square_of_odd_order) works pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If you split the diamonds up like this, you get close to the answer.

1   14  15  28  29  42  43  (172)

2   13  16  27  30  41  44  (173)

3   12  17  26  31  40  45  (174)

4   11  18  25  32  39  46  (175)

5   10  19  24  33  38  47  (176)

6   9   20  23  34  37  48  (177)

7   8   21  22  35  36  49  (178)

Comment: Its closer but not correct. :-)